# Why the local variables can not be initialized with default values?

Tags: java

instance and static variables will be initialized with a default values if we don't initialize with our own values but it doesn't happen with local variables.
Why they designed like so ?

Comment: Sorry about this ....It didn't pop up when I was searching.

Answer (score 3):

The reason we have default values at all is that it's was decided it was too complicated to determine if a variable is initialised before it is used (unless it's final) This is because you could call methods in any order.

For local variable it can determine whether you have used a variable before you gave it a value, so this check prevents you using uninitialised values to avoid errors in your code.